# Fresh project symfony 3 - error 500

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I install Symfony 3 on remote server - Ubuntu (not localhost, VPS), but when I visit in browser myexampleproject.com/project/web/app.php display white page. I checked in console firebug, there is HTTP error 500. I add chmod resursive 777 to logs and cache. I deleted cache.

Hmm. When I run command in putty to open address http://localhost:8000 with lynx, there is okey, symfony is runned correct.

So. How open and run symfony with browser? I tryied php bin/console server:start myexampleproject.com and in response is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `app.php` from your URL:

```
myexampleproject.com/project/web/
```

Also, you should use the folder path "../projectweb" as part of DocumentRoot (if you are using Apache) instead; then you would instead use:

```
myexampleproject.com/
```